# Long narrative set to music, recorded in oil tank, storm called "Honolulu Lou"

Tags: identify-this-song

Back in the 60's I heard a long musical piece that I can't call a song, rather it was more a story set to music. I can only remember bits of what I heard.

1. There was a tropical storm in the Pacific called "Honolulu Lou"
2. There was a wind coming from a piano.
3. The DJ said it was recorded in an empty oil tank.

That is meager information, but it is all I have.

Comment: [Welcome to Music Fans Stack Exchange](http://musicfans.stackexchange.com/tour). I hope you can take a look here for learn [how you can improve your question](http://meta.musicfans.stackexchange.com/a/368/1721) 
and increase your chances for find the music you're looking for.

Comment: I'm still doing research and have not come up with exactly what you are looking for , but I came up with a 1963 hit titled Honolulu Lulu by Jan and Dean that is "surfer" Beach Boys like and another song called Honolulu Lou by blues artist from the 20's named Daisy Martin. Neither have the story structure you're looking for nor could I find anything about recording in an oil tank.

Answer (score 1):

It's a long shot, but could this possibly be Brian Wilson's infamous "lost" album *Smile* (finally officially released in 2004)?

It's a 60's era concept album with a long narrative structure, and a segment set in Hawaii with lyrics that sound a little bit like "Honolulu Lou" (although it's actually Hawaiian language lyrics, "wa halla loo lay").

On the negative side, I haven't been able to find any info about it being recorded in an oil tank, and since it wasn't officially released, it would have been unlikely to have featured on a radio broadcast.

Comment: Definitely not. The storm was called quite clearly Honolulu Lou in good plain English. Nothing was set in Hawaii. It was probably a novelty one off by someone never heard form again.